# function and derivative converging to constants implies derivative is 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've been working on this problem from my textbook.

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,\infty$). Show that if $f'(x) \to L$ as $x \to \infty$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x} \to L$ as $x \to \infty$. Deduce that if $f(x) \to M$ as $x \to \infty$, then $L = 0$

The first part seems like an easy application of L'hospital's rule, except the rule is stated in my book in a way that doesn't make the leap totally straightfoward:

Let $-\infty \le a \lt b \le \infty$ and let $f$ and $g$ be diffentiable in $(a,b)$ with $g'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in (a,b)$. Suppose that 
$\lim_{x\to a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$ $$$$
and that either $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a+}g(x) = 0$ $$$$ or that $\lim_{x\to a+}|g(x)| = \infty +$ $$$$ then $\lim_{x\to a+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$
$$$$
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to take this theorem to the case $x\to \infty$